# New to Mathematica - Plotting Log functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am struggling quite a bit with plotting a couple of simple Log functions on Mathematica: h(n) = n*Log10(n) and i(n) = n^2 + (n*Log10(n)). What I currently have typed in:

```
f[n_] := n
g[n_] := n^2
h[n_] := n Log10[n]
i[n_] := (n^2 + (n Log10[n]))
pf = Plot[f[n], {n, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red]
pg = Plot[g[n], {n, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
ph = Plot[h[x], {n, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Green]
pi = Plot[i[n], {n, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
```

The plots that correspond to the two Log functions are inexplicably blank ☹ What is the syntax for plotting a Log10 function that has another term? Additionally, I eventually want all four graphs to be on one plot. The syntax for that would be `Show[pf, pg, ph, pi]`, correct?

Comment: In this expression `Plot[h[x], {n, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Green]` you probably mean `n` where you have `x`.  Aside from that I see nothing wrong and those plots look fine and dandy when I run your code.

Comment: oh my god i hate myself